# Error while exiting the Camera2BasicFragment (Android custom camera using Camera2 API) to display captured image in next activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera2, android-image-capture

I've used the sample code from Google to implement a custom camera using Camera2 API. I want to display the captured image in the next activity.

[Camera2Basic sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)

However, I'm unable to safely exit the Camera2BasicFragment and start the next activity to display the captured image.

This is the code where I'm trying to start the next activity:

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
            = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage(), mFile));

            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayImage.class));
        }

    };
```

This is the function which saves the image and crops it. I'm not sure if the cropping is right. I just want to be able to display the image in the next activity first. The camera must be working fine when I return for capturing more images later.

```
 private class ImageSaver implements Runnable {

        /**
         * The JPEG image
         */
        private final Image mImage;
        /**
         * The file we save the image into.
         */
        private final File mFile;

        ImageSaver(Image image, File file) {
            mImage = image;
            mFile = file;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            FileOutputStream output = null;
            try {
                output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                output.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                mImage.close();
                if (null != output) {
                    try {
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            capturedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

            int width = linearLayout.getWidth();
            int height = linearLayout.getHeight();

            int left = width/6;
            int top = height/8;

            croppedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(capturedImage, left, top, 5*(width/6), 2*(height/3));

        }

    }
```

Comment: I am having the exact same problem trying to startActivity inside onImageAvailable method. Have you found a solution to it?